# Backbone: populate multiple drop-downs with the same data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I’m working with backbone, this is the static data I have:

```
var emailfields = new EmailFields([
    new EmailField({ id: "data-email", name: "Email" }),
    new EmailField({ id: "data-first-name", name: "First Name" }),
    new EmailField({ id: "data-last-name", name: "Last Name" }), 
]);
```

I want to create n (n > 1) drop-down lists populated with the same data (emailfields). If any of the values is selected I want to notify the user that he cannot select the same field again.

This is my view:

```
EmailFieldSelectView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "addSingleEmailField", "add");
        this.add();
    },

    addSingleEmailField: function(emailfield) {
        $("select").each(function() { 
            $(this).append(new EmailFieldView({ model: emailfield}).render().el);
        });
    },

    add: function() {
        this.collection.each(this.addSingleEmailField);
    },

});
```

This is my initialization:

```
window.emailview = new EmailFieldSelectView({
    collection: emailfields
});
```

In order to populate each select with the same data I’m using $("select").

Is there a better way to do that (I feel this looks like a hack)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got seems like a reasonable way to approach things.  You could use a template to reduce the javascript and need for a view to create select list options.

```
<script type="text/template" id="exampleTemplate">

  <select id="list1">
  <% _(emailFields).each(function(emailField) { %>
    <option value="<%= emailField.id %>"><%= emailField.name %></option>
  <% }); %>
  </select>

  <select id="list2">
  <% _(emailFields).each(function(emailField) { %>
    <option value="<%= emailField.id %>"><%= emailField.name %></option>
  <% }); %>
  </select>

  etc.

</script>
```

Then the view becomes -

```
EmailFieldSelectView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _template($('#exampleTemplate').html());

  initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, "addSingleEmailField", "add");
      this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({ emailFields: this.collection.toJSON() }));
    return this;  
  }

});
```